# XCode Simulator view (not display) is cut off

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I just started using XCode and my simulator is acting weird. On launch, it only displays lower half of the screen while the upper half is cut off. And on resizing simulator window, simulator view doesn't readjusts itself instead its cut off. 
I set the project properties to universal devices.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/khm5t.jpg

Comment: Try adjusting using these 3 commands, command+1 or command+2 or command+3

Comment: You should accept the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Simulator opens, go to `Window -> Scale -> 50%`.
You can change the simulator scale based on the resolution of your screen.